# How can I access Skype for Web on Ubuntu phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, skype

WebRTC should be working fine on Ubuntu phone, so I want to access Skype for Web on it. When I attempt to access https://web.skype.com using the default browser, I am presented with the Skype message:

> Sorry, Skype for Web (Beta) isn't available on this device yet.

I want the browser to send the appropriate information to the Skype site such that it believes that it is a standard desktop browser like Firefox so that the browser with at least be granted an attempt at running Skype for Web. How could this be achieved? For example, how can the browser be made to use a particular user agent string?